# What are the replacements of `inetd` and `/etc/inetd.conf` in Ubuntu?

Tags: systemd, inetd

`inetd` is a service dispatcher for services recorded in `/etc/inetd.conf`.

In Lubuntu 18.04, there is no `/etc/inetd.conf`. `ps -A | grep inetd` returns nothing. What are the replacements of `inetd` and `/etc/inetd.conf`?

I do not have `/etc/xinetd*`.

Thanks.

Comment: Does Lubuntu use systemd? If so, see http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html

Comment: Yeah, `systemd` provides yet another alternative over the old style `inetd` and `xinetd`.  But `xinetd` still works, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The replacement to inetd is ... inetd. You just have to install it, if it's not installed by default (a quick search show packages like openbsd-inetd, inetutils-inetd, xinetd, etc). inetd is not some mandatory component because many systems don't need it (most services -- sshd, samba, ... can do their own listening and forking).

Answer (score 3):

Many Linux's use `xinetd` and so the file is `/etc/xinetd.conf`.  However, it's normally better to put services into files in `/etc/xinetd.d`

e.g. the file `/etc/xinetd.d/time` may contain

```
# This is the tcp version.
service time
{
        disable         = yes
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = time-stream
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        user            = root
        wait            = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service time
{
        disable         = yes
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = time-dgram
        socket_type     = dgram
        protocol        = udp
        user            = root
        wait            = yes
}
```

On my machine I have an `nntp` entry for `leafnode`:

```
% cat /etc/xinetd.d/nntp 
service nntp
{
        disable = no
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = news
        flags           = IPv6
        server          = /usr/local/leafnode/sbin/leafnode
}
```

If `xinetd` isn't installed then you can just install it; eg `sudo apt-get install xinetd`

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: `xinetd` is available in RedHat 6, 7, 8 (and so CentOS and other rebuilds); in Debian 9, 10 (and so likely in most downstream derivatives).

Comment: Thanks. I actually downloaded inetdutils-inetd package fro Debian 10 for easy conformance with the 'netperf' utility, whose manual documents an inetd entry, as it was initially a project based on HP-UX. Worked seamlessly (except I still have to manually start the service :-) But that's just laziness.